# Rails+Bootstrap Modal renders but doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I can get the modal to render in the DOM, but I can't get it to show, I get it to flash for an instant, but it doesn't stay. Here is the relevant code.

tasks_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end   
end
```

edit.js.erb

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#edit_task_modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'tasks/edit_task_modal') %>");
  $("#edit_task_modal").modal('show');
});
```

_edit_task_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button id="close_edit_task_modal" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="edit_task_modal_label">Edit Task</h4>
    </div>
    <%= form_for(:task, url: {action: 'update', id: @task.id},:html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <%= render(partial: 'form', locals: {f: f}) %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit 'Save Changes', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_task_div.html.erb

```
<div class="task well">
  <a>Title: <%= "#{task.title}" %></a><br/>
  Description: <%= "#{task.description}" %> <br>
  Status: <%= "#{task.status}" %> <br>
  Due Date: <%= "#{task.due_date}" %> <br>
  Completed Date: <%= "#{task.completed_date}" %> <br>
  <div style='text-align:right;'>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', {controller: 'tasks', action: 'edit', id: task.id},  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#edit_task_modal'}  %>    
  </div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<div id="edit_task_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit_task_modal_label" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

EDIT: Added modal code

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Where's the actual `<div class="modal" id="edit_task_modal">`? It's not in any of your snippets.

Comment: What do you wanna do? I guess that pushing when **new** button or **edit** link in **index.html.erb** page, show up modal dialog there for creating or updating the task. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct.  The form does render in the DOM and is hooked up to the controller correctly to create or update the task.  I just can't get the modal to appear in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was remove `'data-toggle'='modal'` from the link to the modal.  The javascript was showing it, then the html would toggle it making it hidden again.